# Navigate to overriden Standard New Page with LWC NavigationMixin

Tags: lightning, aura, button-overrides, quickaction, lightning-web-components

Many Standard New buttons in my apps are overriden using Aura components. The do some Apex and then redirect to the real standard new pages. I now migrated such components to LWC. Where I had this in my Aura code:

```
$A.get("e.force:createRecord")
    .setParams({
          "entityApiName": sObjectName,
          "recordTypeId": result
}).fire();
```

I now have this in my LWC code:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: this.type,
            actionName: 'new'
        }
});
```

But, the problem is, this doesn't navigate to the real standard new page, it again goes to the overridden one. #EndlessBrowserLoop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a yet undocumented state property that helps here:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: this.type,
            actionName: 'new'
        },
        state: {
            nooverride: '1'
        }
});
```